# Optimizing DataFrame Filtering in Pandas

Tags: python, pandas, dataframe

I am working on a problem where for every member I need to get all the records within 2 years from their last records in the dataframe (df). The dataframe 'df' which can be constructed as follows :

```
df = pd.DataFrame(zip(list('M1','M1','M1','M1','M2','M2','M2','M2','M3','M3','M3','M3','M4','M4','M4','M4' ), list('07-27-2021','01-15-2021','08-29-2020','03-16-2015', '07-26-2021','02-15-2021','04-22-2020','08-28-2017', '06-15-2021','03-19-2021','08-27-2020','06-11-2019', '05-05-2021','03-15-2021','11-29-2020','03-16-2015')))
df.columns = ['Member_ID','Date_of_Service']
df['Date_of_Service'] = pd.to_datetime(df['Date_of_Service'])
```

The dataframe 'df' would then look like :

[image]

Next I use df to get the last record for every member as follows :

```
last_claim = df.groupby(['Member_ID'])['Date_of_Service'].apply(max).reset_index()
```

So last_claim would have two columns  Member_ID and Date_of_Service:

Now to get all 2 years of data for every member present in the dataset df, I am doing the following :

```
   data_list = []
        
   # for every member get 2 year of observation history from the last service date
        
   for mid in set(df['Member_ID']):
            delta_last_service = pd.to_datetime(last_claim[last_claim['Member_ID'] == mid]['Date_of_Service'].values[0])
            data_mid = df[df['Member_ID'] == mid]
            data_mid['Delta'] = data_mid['Date_of_Service'].apply(lambda x : (x - delta_last_service)/(np.timedelta64(1,'D')) )
            data_mid = data_mid[(data_mid['Delta'] >= -730) & (data_mid['Delta'] <= 0)]
            data_list.append(data_mid)
        
   data_final = pd.concat(data_list, axis = 0)
```

The output desired would be as follows :

[image: Member_ID, Date_of_Service, Delta M1 M1]

Here column Delta for a member holds the difference between the service date and the maximum service date for that member. 0 in the column means that the service date was the maximum date and '...' means it was a different date and the corresponding days difference is stored. Note that the records which were 730 days before the maximum service date were removed.

In the original dataset, df has 211,000 members and running the above code is taking too long to execute. I would be really grateful if someone could help me optimize this.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You could just use a custom function with [`groupby.transform()`](https://pandas.pydata.org/pandas-docs/stable/reference/api/pandas.core.groupby.DataFrameGroupBy.transform.html):

```
df["Delta"] = df.groupby("Member_ID")["Date_of_Service"].transform(lambda x: (x-max(x)).dt.days)

>>> df
     Member_ID Date_of_Service  Delta
0         M1      2021-07-27      0
1         M1      2021-01-15   -193
2         M1      2020-08-29   -332
3         M1      2015-03-16  -2325
4         M2      2021-07-26      0
5         M2      2021-02-15   -161
6         M2      2020-04-22   -460
7         M2      2017-08-28  -1428
8         M3      2021-06-15      0
9         M3      2021-03-19    -88
10        M3      2020-08-27   -292
11        M3      2019-06-11   -735
12        M4      2021-05-05      0
13        M4      2021-03-15    -51
14        M4      2020-11-29   -157
15        M4      2015-03-16  -2242
```

Then, to keep only the rows within the past two years, you could use `df[df["Delta"]>=-730]`

Answer (score 0):

Here's one way by applying to the group

```
from datetime import timedelta as td
def get_date_range(g):
    max_date = g['Date_of_Service'].max()
    min_date = max_date - td(days=730)
    g['Delta'] = g['Date_of_Service'] - max_date
    return g[g['Date_of_Service'] >= min_date]

df.groupby('Member_ID').apply(get_date_range).reset_index(drop=True)
```

This is assuming you want the delta column. You can just remove that if it is not needed.